# Find missing number from sequence of row data in FME

Tags: fme-form

I have 100 tables.

In each table, there will be 9 row of records stored with unique ID like { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 }

Need to log if there is any missing row in those tables with Unique ID.

For eg:

Below the table, there is missing row 4 and 7. need to find 4 and 7 row.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a reference table containing all 9 rows.  Read this table into your workspace and route into a joiner.  In the joiner specify the input table to be tested and set cardinality to 'Must match zero or one'.  Then the `_matched_records` attribute will contain number of records matched; use a tester to check for when `_matched_records==0` and then route it into whatever action you need.  Something like this:

[image: fme screenshot]

If you have a large number of tables, then you could use a script to iterate over all the files or use the workspace runner.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I like the idea of creating a separate table just for this; especially since you know the numbers will be 1-9.

You could do the same thing fully in FME by using a Creator to create 9 features and testing with a FeatureMerger instead of a Joiner.

Or - in a variation on the @Fezter answer - you could use an AttributeFilter to split the data and then a NoFeatureTester to test which is missing.

[image]

I don't say it's particularly elegant, but it would work, and the Empty/Missing/Null/Unfiltered ports add an element of QA if the ID is something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can achieve this is simply by using a Tester transformer.  It means you don't need to store anything in another table.

I created 100 features and assigned them random integer values from 1 to 11.  I connected  a tester transformer and set the test to

```
ID In 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

[image]

Anything that is in those values will go to the "Passed" output.  Anything else will go to "Failed".

Just like JimT said, you could use a workspace runner.  But I prefer just using a dynamic reader to read all of your CSV files at once.

[image]

Comment: I might be missing something - but how does this detect if a row is missing?

Comment: Agreed. This one would tell you if an ID existed outside the range 1-9, but you would only know if a row is missing by the number of features that pass the test - but you won't know which row(s).

Comment: Right, I think I misunderstood the question. Sorry.